# vim - howto close all buffers in the current tab?

Tags: vim

I know that using a command like:

```
:%bdelete
```

Using this command I can close all buffers, in all tabs, what I'd like to do is to close all buffers open in the current tab, is that possible?

Usage:

What I'd like to do, is to open ViM and load `:VSTreeExplorer` and then open related files in the same window switching between them using `:next` and `:previous` and then open other files a new tab (with VSTreeExplorer as well), when I need to clean one of the tabs, I would like to use whatever command that closes buffers in the current tab.

For now, what I do is use `:%bd` and then open the VSTreeExplorer and start over...

Thanks

Comment: Well congrats, you have answered my question in your question :) (how to close all buffers without exiting Vim)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buffers are global to the Vim instance, not confined to a specific tab page.  A tab page is simply a way to organize windows and windows are simply a way to display a buffer.  Zero or more windows (and therefore tab pages) can display the same buffer.  Getting used to this concept should help your workflow in Vim.

The [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/) has a couple pages that give some more [explanation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages) and [tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_tips_for_using_tab_pages) for using tab pages.

Comment: I thought so!

Thank you for your answer and I'll read the Tip to get used to the workflow...

Answer (score 18):

If you're done with a tab you can just use `:tabclose`.

Comment: Yea I know about :tabclose, except closing a tab won't close the buffers previously opened by this tab, my question was how to close a tab along with all the buffer that *this* tab had, anyway I know now that it can't be done..

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 18):

`:windo bd` will delete all buffers in the current tab.

Comment: Is this any different than `:tabclose`? It closes the tab for me.

Comment: I should have checked before asking. `:tabclose` closes the tab (window) but does not delete the buffers, which is actually what I would expect given how tabs actually work in Vim. With that said, I'd say your answer (`:windo bd`) is objectively the closest solution, however understanding how tabs work in Vim as the chosen answer suggests explains *why* `:tabclose` and `:windo bd` behave differently.